# PHP -Regex to validate images and link

Tags: php, regex

I'm validating form fields.I tried this regex for image '/^[.jpg|.png|.gif|.bmp]$/i but i think is regex is not correct.

How do i validated links,i only want to check whether the link has HTTP/HTTPS/WWW

Proper link should be . I do not wnat ot check domain,i see many domains ending in different forms line .rs etc.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: No your regex shouldnt have starts with .jpg if thats done on the whole name - you would need to show code, errors, etc.

Comment: @BugFinder:If i upload .jpg ,it is showing upload only images error.My regex is wrong.What is the regex to validate photos.

Answer (score 2):

Check image format (format case-insensitive):

```
"([^\s]+(\.(?i)(jpe?g|png|gif|bmp))$)"
```

Examples :

```
"Test.jpg" OK
"Test.JPEG" OK
"Test.BMP" OK
```

Check url (HTTP or HTTPS or WWW):

```
"((http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?(www.)?(([a-zA-Z0-9-]){2,}\.){1,4}([a-zA-Z]){2,6}(\/([a-zA-Z-_\/\.0-9#:?=&;,]*)?)?)"
```

Comment: :Images and link regex separately.

Comment: :What does question mark do in image format.It will only check whether user has uploaded image only not any thing else.

Answer (score 0):

To validate images, this is the regex:

```
'/\.(jpg|png|gif|bmp)$/i'
```

You can add any postfixes as needed.